# How to use my phone as ''emulator'' on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, emulation

I know I can use my phone to debug and run application on Android Studio. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to run on my phone, but I see on my computer. I mean, it looks like a emulator, but with my data and apps, you know? Like create a mirror on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

There is way to project the screen of your phone to your computer check out scrcpy.
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Answer (score 1):

As an easier advice from me you can use screen mirroring software like mobizen,Vysor,AirDroid and for samsung devices you can use samsung flow.

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring of Android device screens is also available in Android Studio directly as an experimental feature in Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1. See https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#device-mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

First must set your divice to delevopers mode

- set anable on install aplication via USB
- i used vysor aplication just install on your device and your pc
- and run aplication in your android studio

Answer (score 0):

now you can connect your mobile with pc using wi-fi
first you should turn on developer mode
then turn on wireless debugging and connect your mobile with pc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).